# Passing touch events through ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement a UI where there is a full-page `<ScrollView />` with a `<View />` positioned absolutely underneath it. The `<ScrollView />` has padding at the top, so initially the `<View />` is visible and then the `<ScrollView />` scrolls up to cover it. The issue, of course, is that the `<View />` does not receive touches, as they're being eaten up by the `<ScrollView />` responder.

Is there any way right now to implement or subclass `<View />` such that you can pass events through to underlying elements?

Comment: Which platform are you targeting? This may not work for you, but if you set the scrollview background to transparent, that may help in iOS. I believe it's iOS that passes touch events through transparent overlays. I might have that totally backwards, and can't find the reference right now. And, this may not apply to scrollview. But just in case it helps...

Comment: Could you provide a small rnplay app for this issue? It would help to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this Mike? Coming across the same issue ourselves!

Answer (score 2):

You should use an `Animated.View` that accepts `ScrollView`'s `y` offset as an `Animated.Value` prop. Then, you can use that value to perform animations while scrolling the `ScrollView`. The scroll will catch the pan animation and pass it through props to whoever needs it.

One of the best code-samples you'll find for this is Facebook's F8 app. Precisely, this file: https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/b5df451259897d1838933f01ad4596784325c2ad/js/common/ListContainer.js. In that file, `ParallaxBackground` gets the offset `Animated.Value` that comes from the ListView children.